# Two separate drive setup and getting cannot import 'xxxxx': no such pool exists

Tags: hard-drive, zfs, mount, boot

I have a simple freeNAS setup (FreeNAS-9.10.2-U6 (561f0d7a1)) that accesses two independent drives, no mirroring.

Have not really accessed the system in a while and after a power loss I needed to boot it and now on both disks appear to not be mounting.

During boot at the Beginning ZFS volume imports I get the following:

```
cannot import 'NAS-5TB-01': no such pool or dataset
        Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source

cannot import 'NAS-5TB-01-Backup': no such pool or dataset
        Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source
```

I have not run any commands on this as the data is fairly critical.

Is there a way to recover from this and access the data on the drives?  Like I said they are just separate shares that I need to be able to mount.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The odds are quite likely your data is lost... this is why it's been repeatedly recommended in the FreeNAS Forum to have a Pure Sine Wave UPS connected to the server.  To understand why your data is likely unrecoverable, you'll want to use the search function in the FreeNAS forum.  You can try to recover the data, but due to how ZFS writes to disk, the odds are not good... If you are able to recover the pool(s), it's likely all data since the last shutdown/reboot will be lost. Either way, the FreeNAS Forum would be the correct medium. On a side note, I'd also recommend upgrading to FreeNAS 11.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you have important data on the disks, I would first make a low-level copy on another machine to another disk, just to be sure. That said, normally nothing bad should happen as long as you don't actually try to import the pool and just look for it...

I don't know the exact commands used in FreeBSD, but generally I would do it this way:

1. Check if hardware is present and without obvious damage, check/replug/replace cables (but do not swap disks around)
2. Check if SAS/SATA controller is working and disks are recognized (I think `geom disk list` should do that)
3. Check if names/IDs of disks differ from that what ZFS would expect
4. Run `zpool import` to show any importable pools
5. If found, run `zpool import <id>` along with the various options (destroyed only, force, readonly, nomount etc.) that are explained in the `man zpool` help (it depends on your specific situation and data loss may occur here)